# Solving Laplace's Equation in Cylindrical Coordinates.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates. The problem only has radial dependence so Laplace's equation reduces to:

$$
\nabla ^2V = \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dV(r)}{dr} \right) = 0
$$

I tried integrating both sides of the equation but I wasn't sure how to actually carry out the integral. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Multiply both sides by $r$ first. Can you integrate then?

Answer (score 0):

$$\nabla ^2V = \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dV(r)}{dr} \right) = 0$$
$$ \frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dV(r)}{dr} \right) = 0$$
$$ rV' = C_1$$
$$ V' = \dfrac {C_1}r$$
$$V(r)=C_1 \ln r +C_2$$